# Postsharp Installation Error

Tags: postsharp

I am trying to install postsharp express 4.1 but the installation fails with an error "Proxy Authentication Required".

I have both Visual studio 2012 and 2015 installed on my machine. Below is the trace in postsharp log file. Any suggestions will help.

```
 PostSharp.HQ.v3.0.exe Information: 0 : Registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions does not exist.
Leaving: VsxUtilities.MustInstallVsx(this = {PostSharp.HQ.Vsx.VsxUtilities}, {PostSharp.HQ.Vsx.VsxPackage}, {4.2.22}) : True
PostSharp.HQ.v3.0.exe Information: 0 : detectedVsUpdateVersion (14.0.23107) is unknown or sufficient - package PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio 2015 can be installed.
PostSharp.HQ.v3.0.exe Warning: 0 : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at PostSharp.HQ.Vsx.VsxProcess.InstallVsxTask.GetDownloadUrl(String searchString, String vsixId, Version requiredVsVersion) in c:\src\PostSharp-4.1\UserInterface\PostSharp.HQ\Vsx\VsxProcess.cs:line 482
   at PostSharp.HQ.Vsx.VsxProcess.InstallVsxTask.<Execute>d__13.MoveNext() in c:\src\PostSharp-4.1\UserInterface\PostSharp.HQ\Vsx\VsxProcess.cs:line 385
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at PostSharp.HQ.Vsx.VsxProcess.InstallVsxTask.GetDownloadUrl(String searchString, String vsixId, Version requiredVsVersion) in c:\src\PostSharp-4.1\UserInterface\PostSharp.HQ\Vsx\VsxProcess.cs:line 482
   at PostSharp.HQ.Vsx.VsxProcess.InstallVsxTask.<Execute>d__13.MoveNext() in c:\src\PostSharp-4.1\UserInterface\PostSharp.HQ\Vsx\VsxProcess.cs:line 385<---
```

Answer (score 1):

NuGet Package Manager extension is essential component for PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio, so installer tries to download a NuGet Package Manager extension from Visual Studio Gallery if it is not installed or it doesn't meet a minimal version requirement (NuGet 2.2 for VS2012 and VS2013 and NuGet 3.0 for VS2015).

In this case a proxy authentication is required and PostSharp doesn't handle this case well.

As a workaround, you can install the NuGet Package Manager extension manually. Installer should not try to access Visual Studio Gallery in this case and WebException should not be thrown.